# Running Model on Feature Class with Attachments Enabled

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-portal, attachments

I have a question regarding ArcGIS ModelBuilder. I've created a model that calculates a few fields. It runs flawlessly when attachments are **NOT** enabled on the feature class. However, I need the ability to have attachments enabled on this layer. When I run the model with attachments enabled I get:

> RuntimeError: Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit
> session [MES_Suvey.DBO.MI.South]

Does any one know if it is possible to start an editing session within ModelBuilder?

I know I can manually enter a session within ArcMap and run successfully but I am also publishing the model as a geoprocessing service and it fails when run from a web map if the feature class has attachments enabled.

Comment: Which version of ArcMap?

Comment: @KHibma ArcMap Version 10.8.1

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved, this is a known limitation.

You have to Disable attachments.

And in case you are using any cursor(InsertCursor), use it outside an edit session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Calculate Value` tool of the Model Builder. The main idea behind this tool to make your model flexible enough to accommodate full power of python (including arcpy package). For example, a simple case would be:

[image]

where the Code block is as follows for demonstration, where it assumes inline variable of `field_to_be_calculated` is a string field and all values will be changed to **"new value"**:

```
def calculate_field_in_editing_session(fc, fld):
    ws = arcpy.os.path.dirname(fc)

    with arcpy.da.Editor(ws) as edit:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, fld, '"new value"', 'PYTHON')
    return fc
```

[image]

Please note, this workaround uses a Feature Class as an input and if the input is a feature layer, you need to use layer's data source property to be able to set workspace (e.g., `ws = arcpy.os.path.dirname(fc.dataSource)`).

I presume that you will be fine when publishing the model as a geoprocessing service since some ESRI examples use `Calculate Value`.